# Core data is only returning one object instead of all the objects

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

i have the below core data:

[image]

---

what I am trying to do is fetch all the **producto** that has as **categoria.name** the value **"carne"** and at the same time has as **supermercado.name** the value **"Mercadona"**

in sql would look like something like this:

```
select p.*
from producto as p inner join categoria as c on p.id = c.producto_id
                   inner join supermercado as s on p.id = s.producto_id
where c.name = "carne" AND s.name = "Mercadona";
```

In sql would be easy, we make a join, and in the where clause we filter the elements that we want to select.

---

One time, we know what we want to do I have tried to write this queries with the predicates that core data and swift offer to us. But I am not obtaining good results.

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(supermercados, $supermercado, ANY $supermercado.name == %@).@count > 0", super_name)
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(categorias, $categoria, ANY $categoria.name == %@).@count > 0",categoria)

fetchrequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
```

I write the two predicates and then join them with an and predicate, but I only have one problem. Is that **should return 3 products**:  "**rioja**" and "**carne_demigrante**" but only return me one object not all

When I wrote that predicates without the subquery I had exactly the same problem that it only returned one object instead of the 3 that I have in **"producto"** with that properties.

---

so the question of one millions dollars is, how can I return **all** the objects that has this conditions instead of only return **ONE** object?

Comment: I wonder whether the root of your problem is that you have not implemented inverses for two of the relationships: I think CoreData will therefore assume that each Categoria is related to only one Producto and one Supermercado.

Comment: Umm I am going to make some change and reply here, apart from this do u see nice my predicates?

Comment: i have edited the data model making a relationship between categoria and supermercado, producto but I have the same error. Its only return me only one object instead of all :( I want to cry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to use SUBQUERY instead of a more straightforward "join"

```
let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "ANY supermercados.name like %@", super_name)
let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "ANY categorias.name like %@" ,categoria)

fetchrequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [p1, p2])
```

Comment: because I don't understand how exactly core data works. My boss said me do this and this, and for learn I have put myself this example and I have walk around by all the webs and I don't find any solution to solve the problem that I have. How can I do this with the join?

Comment: So it doesn’t work if you create a compound predicate like in your question?

Comment: it works but if I have 3 objects with that conditions, it only returns one. Not three. I want to return all the objects.

Comment: I had an error in my answer that I fixed, removed ‘$’ in front of entity name. I don’t understand how you can get only one object back instead of 3 with my predicates combined. Assuming you really have 3 matching objects you should get all 3 or none back, not one.

Comment: nop, it doesn't work. Only return one object, I don't know what is happening. For that reason I investigated and I discover that the subquery was for return more than one object, so I tried to use it without any good result. Any other possible solution?

Comment: I just saw that your Supermercado entity also has a relationship to Categoria, this might be what makes the fetch fail. Maybe you need to include this as well?

Comment: you have given mi an idea, instead of doing a predicate filtering by categoria and another by supermercado, doing only one with supermercado.name and supermercado.categoria.name. I am going to try and say something.